# Math results in scientific float and cannot calculate with it anymore

Tags: xslt, mono, scientific-notation

I am trying to make an xslt that can convert a position (vector3) via a quaternion to a new position. I have made the following set-up, but I am retrieving `NaN`'s for very small values close to 0. How can I calculate further with the values that come from the quaternion to right-vector calculations?

```
<xsl:template name="object_markingtape_position">
  <xsl:param name="sign"/> <!-- left or right (-1 or 1) -->
  <xsl:param name="quaternion"/> <!-- quaternion in x,y,z,w -->
  <xsl:variable name="rightvec">
    <xsl:call-template name="QuatToRight">
      <xsl:with-param name="x" select="$quaternion/ns:x"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="y" select="$quaternion/ns:y"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="z" select="$quaternion/ns:z"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="w" select="$quaternion/ns:w"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>

  Right vector y: <xsl:value-of select="number($rightvec/y)"/> <!-- results in a value with 1.5435434E-04 -->
  <xsl:element name="position" namespace="{$ns}">
    <xsl:element name="x" namespace="{$ns}">
      <xsl:value-of select="$sign * 1.5 * $rightvec/x + ns:position/ns:x"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="y" namespace="{$ns}"> <!-- results into NaN -->
      <xsl:value-of select="$sign * 1.5 * $rightvec/y + ns:position/ns:y"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="z" namespace="{$ns}">
      <xsl:value-of select="$sign * 1.5 * $rightvec/z + ns:position/ns:z"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Functionality for calculating the vectors from a quaternion -->
<!-- From http://nic-gamedev.blogspot.nl/2011/11/quaternion-math-getting-local-axis.html -->
<xsl:template name="QuatToRight">
  <xsl:param name="x"/>
  <xsl:param name="y"/>
  <xsl:param name="z"/>
  <xsl:param name="w"/>
  <xsl:element name="vec3">
    <xsl:element name="x">
      <xsl:value-of select="1 - 2 * ($x * $y - $w * $z)"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="y">
      <xsl:value-of select="2 * ($x * $y + $w * $z)"/> 
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="z">
      <xsl:value-of select="2 * ($x * $z - $w * $y)"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

An example of xml values that can come in are the following:

```
<Item>
  <position>
    <x>-106.6172</x>
    <y>0.780673563</y>
    <z>-13.0446815</z>
  </position>
  <rotation> <!-- this is where the quaternion param is filled with -->
    <x>0.0810996</x>
    <y>0.354339659</y>
    <z>-0.207844481</z>
    <w>-0.908111751</w>
  </rotation>
</Item>
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the input XML?

Comment: Which processor are you using? Your best option might be using extension functions.

Comment: @MiMo I have added a partial xml example. All params and variables are filled correctly, but I just have an issue with bringing 8237489234E-04 back to a real number to work with.

Comment: @StanleyDeBoer I am using Unity3D, which has a .NET 2.0 C# subset. I cannot say if I can just use extensions. This is XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this with some data loss, but it is the cleanest solution so far. I used `format-number()`.

```
<xsl:template name="QuatToRight">
  <xsl:param name="x"/>
  <xsl:param name="y"/>
  <xsl:param name="z"/>
  <xsl:param name="w"/>
  <xsl:element name="vec3">
    <xsl:element name="x">
      <xsl:value-of select="format-number(1 - 2 * ($x * $y - $w * $z),'0.000000')"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="y">
      <xsl:value-of select="format-number(2 * ($x * $y + $w * $z),'0.000000')"/> 
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="z">
      <xsl:value-of select="format-number(2 * ($x * $z - $w * $y),'0.000000')"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find a better solution you might have to resort to using extension functions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:quat="urn:myExtension" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="quat msxsl" version="1.0">
<xsl:param name="x"/>
<xsl:param name="y"/>
<xsl:param name="z"/>
<xsl:param name="w"/> 

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:value-of select="quat:calcQuat($x, $y, $z, $w)"/>
</xsl:template>

<msxsl:script implements-prefix="quat" language="c#">
    <![CDATA[       
    public string calcQuat(double x, double y, double z, double w)
    {           
        double result = 1 - 2 * (x * y - w * z)
        return Double.ToString(result)
    }      

    ]]>
</msxsl:script>
```

Comment: When I try this, I get an `XsltException: Stylesheet script compile error`. What is urn:myExtension? Can you give me a reference of how this works?

Answer (score 0):

There are three problems I can see:

- the variable `rightvec` contains an XML fragment, but is then used as a node-set - this requires a conversion to work usually (but it depends on the XSLT processor)
- the named template `object_markingtape_position` references an element `ns:position` in the current context, so its result depends on where it is called - better to pass the position as a parameter;
- the named tamplate `QuatToRight` generates a `vec3` element containing sub-elements with the values, but its result is then used as if there was not `vec3` intermediate element.

Using the .NET XSLT processor, this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template name="object_markingtape_position">
    <xsl:param name="sign"/> <!-- left or right (-1 or 1) -->
    <xsl:param name="quaternion"/> <!-- quaternion in x,y,z,w -->
    <xsl:param name="position"/> <!-- position in x,y,z -->
    <xsl:variable name="rightvecFragment">
      <xsl:call-template name="QuatToRight">
        <xsl:with-param name="x" select="$quaternion/x"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="y" select="$quaternion/y"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="z" select="$quaternion/z"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="w" select="$quaternion/w"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="rightvec" select="msxsl:node-set($rightvecFragment)"/>

    <xsl:element name="position">
      <xsl:element name="x">
        <xsl:value-of select="$sign * 1.5 * $rightvec/x + $position/x"/>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="y">
        <!-- results into NaN -->
        <xsl:value-of select="$sign * 1.5 * $rightvec/y + $position/y"/>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="z">
        <xsl:value-of select="$sign * 1.5 * $rightvec/z + $position/z"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Functionality for calculating the vectors from a quaternion -->
  <!-- From http://nic-gamedev.blogspot.nl/2011/11/quaternion-math-getting-local-axis.html -->
  <xsl:template name="QuatToRight">
    <xsl:param name="x"/>
    <xsl:param name="y"/>
    <xsl:param name="z"/>
    <xsl:param name="w"/>
    <xsl:element name="x">
      <xsl:value-of select="1 - 2 * ($x * $y - $w * $z)"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="y">
      <xsl:value-of select="2 * ($x * $y + $w * $z)"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="z">
      <xsl:value-of select="2 * ($x * $z - $w * $y)"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:call-template name="object_markingtape_position">
      <xsl:with-param name="sign" select="1"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="position" select="position"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="quaternion" select="rotation"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to the example input produces:

```
<position>
  <x>-104.63717236709732</x>
  <y>1.4331220235568977</y>
  <z>-12.129909788264223</z>
</position>
```

Comment: I changed everything you said, but I still receive the following as output: `<x>-111.6288408761534</x><y>NaN</y><z>-15.460565039376352</z>`

Comment: I don't know what else to suggets. Is the result I am getting the right one?

Comment: Yes it is, but it could be that I am using Mono instead of .NET. It should be the same, but this wouldn't be one of the first issues that I'm having with Mono.